# Using preg_match in DOMXpath for mathing text contgent

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I'm looking for a correct syntax for matching specific pattern `#some_string#` in text content in DOMDocument.

```php
$document = <<<XML
<div>
    <para>text not to match</para>
    <para>Other line #my_pattern_to_match#, hello world</para>
    <block>
        <para>Second test #other_pattern_to_match# in a sub child node</para>
    </block> 
</div>
XML;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions('preg_match');

$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[text()][0 < php:functionString("preg_match", "/\#(.*?)#/")]');
```

i've as result :
`preg_match() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

With :

```php
$nodes = $xpath->query('//para/text()[0 < php:functionString("preg_match", "/\#(.*?)#/")]');
```

an empty `DOMNodeList()`

I'm sure it's the query syntax the problem. But i don't know how to write the correct syntax.

Comment: Your solution look great: my query get all the text who contains the pattern. You wan write an answer i can flag as solution if you want :).

Comment: That is because `preg_match` needs at least two arguments: 1) regex, 2) input string.

Comment: Just FYI - `$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[php:functionString("preg_match", "/\#(.*?)\#/", text())]');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to implement the `preg_match` into an xpath query but you could alternatively just pull all `para` elements and run the regex on them.

```
$document = <<<XML
<div>
    <para>text not to match</para>
    <para>Other line #my_pattern_to_match#, hello world</para>
    <block>
        <para>Second test #other_pattern_to_match# in a sub child node</para>
    </block> 
</div>
XML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($document);
$paras = $dom->getElementsByTagName('para');
foreach($paras as $para){
    if(preg_match('/#(.*?)#/', $para->nodeValue, $match)){
        echo $match[1] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/imChg